# What should we do if an answer contains link rot and there is no other appropriate answer?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through some questions today and stumbled upon this one: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1109/what-is-flag-weight

The answer contains link rot so I searched for what to do in that situation and found this: [What should we do about answers with Link Rot?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2229/what-should-we-do-about-answers-with-link-rot)

The suggested advice is to downvote and leave a comment.  However I was still interested in the answer and I don't feel that this would get the question answered.  I did some searching and it appears flag weight is no more so it doesn't matter but I still want to know what I should have done if I had the same question and the answer is corrupted by link rot.  Should I flag the question?  Ask the same question after flagging the other one for deletion?  What is appropriate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. I up-voted that for some reason, and apparently you can't take back a vote after a certain length of time. Even if the link still worked, it wouldn't be a good answer as it doesn't contain any info besides the link. We encourage people to provide a summery of the information that they are linking to for just this reason.

Still, the advise in "[What should we do about answers with Link Rot?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2229/what-should-we-do-about-answers-with-link-rot)" is probably best.

Leaving a comment will hopefully prompt the user to provide a better answer. Since it really can't be saved through an edit, since it only consists of a dead link, it's probably appropriate to flag the *answer* for deletion.